# Как включить Navigation static в Inspector?

Tags: unity3d

Изучаю C# и Unity по книге "Изучаем C# через разработку игр на Unity" - Пятое издание. Дошел до момента где нужно настроить компонент NavMesh, выбрав Navigation Static в окне Inspector, но данная опция недоступна (неактивна) с подписью "This static value has been deprecated". На форумах пишут что Navigation Static устарел и нужно использовать пакет AI Navigation, но я не понял как его установить. Да и как теперь дальше двигаться по книге? Или на этом моменте придется ее забросить?
Версия Unity 2022.3.6f1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зайдите в Package Manager, найдите и установите AI Navigation. Потом Windows>AI>Navigation(Obsolete). Возле Инспектора появится новое меню, там вкладка Object. В ней и можно выбрать Navigation Static.